# Responsive activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm learning to develop Android application for two months now.
I have a lot of question according to the layouts on Android.

I read [this article](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) and others on the official documentation website (can't find the link). I understand that in order to get a screen for which the size of the elements matches the resolution of the phone, I need to use `Density-independent pixel (dp)` element.

Let's imagine I order my layout according to the documentation :

```
res/layout/main_activity.xml           # For handsets (smaller than 600dp available width)
res/layout-sw600dp/main_activity.xml   # For 7” tablets (600dp wide and bigger)
res/layout-sw720dp/main_activity.xml   # For 10” tablets (720dp wide and bigger)
```

Just talk about the handset configuration. I read in the documentation that `The density-independent pixel is equivalent to one physical pixel on a 160 dpi screen, which is the baseline density assumed by the system for a "medium" density screen`. So what is the maximum height and width I can use in my `res/layout/main_activity.xml` in dp ? If I have the same layout for the 4, 5, 6" phones, how is it possible for me to set an image at 50% of the screen length using dp for example ?

I really must forget something to help me to understand how it works..

Comment: To summarize: use **sp** for text sizes, **dp** at any other place. Best.

Comment: @statosdotcom what are you summarizing? OP didn't even mention sp

Comment: THe max width an height of a device in dp will differ based on the physical dimensions of the phone.  The advantage of dp is that its always the same physical size-  a 160dpx160dp image is always going to be 1 inch by 1 inch.  A 160 pixel by 160 pixel can be anywhere from 1 inch by 1 inch to 1/4 inch by 1/4 inch depending on the density of the device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `PercentRelativeLayout` from `Percent Support Library`, see this example :

```
<android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<View
    android:id="@+id/top_left"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="#ff44aacc"
    app:layout_heightPercent="20%"
    app:layout_widthPercent="70%" />

<View
    android:id="@+id/top_right"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/top_left"
    android:background="#ffe40000"
    app:layout_heightPercent="20%"
    app:layout_widthPercent="30%" />

<View
    android:id="@+id/bottom"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/top_left"
    android:background="#ff00ff22"
    app:layout_heightPercent="80%" />
</android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>
```

the result :

[image]

Don't froget to add `compile 'com.android.support:percent:23.3.0'` in your `build.gradle`

Check this [tutorial](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Constructing-View-Layouts) for more informations how to Constructing View Layouts.

Comment: This [link](https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/know-percent-support-library/en) helped me a lot too !

Comment: Yes defeintly!! happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LinearLayout` and weights of it's children to achieve the desired effect:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="0dp"
               android:layout_weight="1"/> <!-- 50% height -->

    <View android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="0dp"
          android:layout_weight="1"/> <!-- 50% height -->
</LinearLayout>
```

Or you can use the [Percent Support Library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/features.html#percent)